# Will environment variables change due to some reason at heroku?

Tags: heroku

My rails application is running on heroku. Is secret_key_base environment variable changed due to some reason? Also, are there different secret_key_base environment variables set for multiple dyno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku won't change config vars that you set. They may change config vars that are set by addons though.

Comment: I have not set the secret_key_base environment variable.
However, the secret_key_base environment variable was set.
Does heroku set the secret_key_base environment variable automatically?
In that case, will the secret_key_base environment variable change at the timing of restarting dyno?